# Excel formula for every 2 weeks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On my planner I have a section with recurring dates (see pic below) that I use to copy/paste cells into the main body of my planner as needed.

[image]

I use the formula below (Thursday shown) for 'recurring every week', but what about 'recurring every 2 weeks'? I'll need to use the DATE() function I think, copy/paste and then edit the date in the formula each time, I'm OK with that, but struggling to come up with the right formula.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=5,TODAY(),TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+5 + IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>=5,7))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a 2-week switch, I'd go for a weeknumber mod 2:

```
=MOD(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),11),2)
```

This gives 1 for odd, and 0 for even week numbers.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just needed to do this so thought this might help others.

1. Enter the first date (I entered June 6, 2023 into A2 and it made it 06-Jun-23)
2. In the cell below it type `=$` then select the cell with date and add `+14` (for example `=$A2+14`)
3. Select the 2 cells and move your cursor to the bottom right corner until you see a bolded cross (not the move arrow one)
4. Click and drag down for the number of rows you want dates for and excel will do the math of 14 days from the previous cell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).